# Restrict access to few pages when Subdomain is used to access website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vhosts

I have a website which can be accessible via sub-domains as well. e.g

```
www.example.com, abc.example.com and xyz.example.com
```

all three domains points to the same website. The website behaves differently for all 3 domains. Now my problem is I want to restrict access to About Us page and What We Do pages when they are accessed via sub-domains. I know I can do a redirect from PHP but I want to restrict even before the request goes to PHP like in htaccess or vhost file itself. So

```
www.example.com/aboutus - Must work BUT

abc.example.com/aboutus and xyz.example.com/aboutus - must not work
```

I tried to search a lot on web but couldn't find a solution.

Please help

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mod_rewrite you could do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule /aboutus http://www.example.com/errorpage [R,L]
```

That looks for any host not being www.example.com if the url /aboutus is called. For further information see this [docu](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)